# XML parsing:Retrieve multiple rows in xml using digester

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

While parsing an xml file like the one below, i want to get the list of telephone numbers for one particular id.I am using Digester to do this.But i am not understanding how to add the call methods or createobjects .Can anyone help me with this.My xml file contains 1000's of 
     types

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<address-book>
<contact type="individual">
    <id>50</id>
    <city>New York</city>
    <province>NY</province>
    <postalcode>10013</postalcode>
    <country>USA</country>
<address>
    <telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
<telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
<telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
<telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
</address>
</contact>
<contact type="business">
    <id>52</id>
    <city>Zagreb</city>
    <province></province>
    <postalcode>10000</postalcode>
    <country>Croatia</country>
<address>
    <telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
<telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
<telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
<telephone>1-212-345-6789</telephone>
</address>
</contact>
```

Also how should i stop the parsing when i get the required Id.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question was specific to using the apache-commons-digester, this can be solved by the host of libraries already available in the XML families of functions - namely a SAX parser coupled with an XPath search. Instead of brute-forcing through the data, if what is being searched is known, an XPath query can find the data relatively efficiently. Otherwise, if traversing the entire set of data for indexing or other purposes, again, recommend using a simple SAX parser and looping through the elements (again possibly via an //MyElement type XPath query) and then for each instance, pass the value to a function for indexing or whatever operation. The apache-commons-digester may be overly complicated and/or slow for what is needed.